# django-registration-redux falls with "Import error" exception

Tags: django, authentication

I have installed in my virtualenv django-reg.-redux
then i have added 'registration' app in INSTALLED_APPS,
but when i type python manage.py migrate 
What package i have missed?[stacktrace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CumcD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually update the `admin.py` file inside the registration app.

Open up [`registration\admin.py`](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/admin.py#L3) and then use the following import:

```
from django.contrib.sites.requests import RequestSite
```

instead of the wrong import:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
```